# Renaming table results in CREATE statement rather than ALTER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

In a .sqlproj I have changed the name of a table (amongst other changes).
I did the renaming in Visual Studio 2012 through the right click 'refactor' option.
When I try to publish the changes, the deployment script has a CREATE TABLE command rather than an ALTER TABLE command for the table renaming. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you see different if you do a schema compare? Any chance that columns are in a different order compared to your original project or that the clustered index is different or something else that could result in a rebuild?

Comment: @PeterSchott thanks, but it turns out the __RefactorLog table was missing so the script was skipping all the refactoring steps and just CREATEing rather than ALTERing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gotten to the root of my problem. The database to which I was publishing the script was a copy (bacpac) of the true database. The bacpac was missing the dbo.__RefactorLog table, so when running the script it was ignoring the refactorlog file and just creating the database.

Answer (score 0):

You would alter something that already exists, since the script creates table you should have left it as `CREATE TABLE` you changing the name in script doesnt do anything but tries to change the name of a table that does not exists which will obviously result in an error.

Also if you already have a table say called `foo` and you would like to change its name from `foo` to say `bar` you wont use Alter table command but the following system stored procedure .

```
EXECUTE sp_rename 'dbo.foo', 'bar'
```

Comment: The table already exists and I am trying to rename it. However, the rename results in a CREATE rather than an ALTER in the deployment script.

Comment: Right if the table already exists then use the above statement rather than using alter table statement

Comment: I'm not sure you are familiar with the approach I am using to make the database changes. The deployment script is generated for me based on the changes I've made to the project.